# Logback to capture all logs displayed in adb logcat

Tags: android, logback

Currently logback captures all the logs to a file that are mentioned via error, debug etc.

Apart from this logs, in Android Studio logcat we could we other logs that are provided by other apps or by the Android System.

Is there a mechanism to include all the logs that are available in adb logcat to the logs created using logback?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no :

- For security reason, an application can only see its own logcat, since Android 4.1 (API 16) there is no way for it to access logs from other applications or from the system.
- While it is possible to add logback events to the logcat with a suitable appender, the other way around is not easy. There is no API to access the logcat events. The only solution would be for the application to launch the `adb logcat` command (without the usual `-d` flag), continuously read its output and create logback events.